# MySQL won't install in CentOS due to conflict with mariadb

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, centos

I just installed CentOS Linux and then downloaded the MySQL `tar` file to install MySQL.  I extracted the 6 enclosed `rpm` files, and clicked on the `-server` `rpm` file to install it.  But I get the following dialog box error:

```
Failed to install file  
Two packages provide the same name.  
This is usually due to mixing packages from different software sources.
```

When I try to run install it from the Linux terminal, I get the following more specific log, which seems to indicate a conflict with mariadb:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install /path/to/Downloads/MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining /path/to/Downloads/MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm: MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
Marking /path/to/Downloads/MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MySQL-server.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
Package Arch Version Repository Size
================================================================================
Installing:
```

MySQL-server x86_64 5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5
/MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 253 M

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install 1 Package

Total size: 253 M
Installed size: 253 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test

Transaction check error:
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I am brand new to Linux though I have been using MySQL in Windows for a long time.  This is a completely new installation of Linux, and this is the first software I am installing, so the only pre-existing software I can imagine would be something bundled in CentOS 7.  Apparently MariaDB is pre-installed in CentOS 7, but how do I handle this?

I found [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73507) on the Oracle web site, but I don't know what to make of it, as I am brand new to Linux.

Comment: Did you already have a mysql package installed? What does `rpm -qa mysql*` say?

Comment: @EtanReisner I just opened `terminal` and typed in `rpm -qa mysql*` then hit return.  It just gave another command prompt with no other information.

Comment: What do you get if you run `yum install <the -server rpm file you clicked on>`?

Comment: @EtanReisner it says i need to be root to perform this command. I have the root password, but how do i open terminal as root?

Comment: There might be a menu entry for that. Alternatively try `sudo yum ...` (I don't know if CentOS sets that up by default at this point). If that doesn't work then you can run `su -` to get a root shell and then run the yum command.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you.  When I type in `sudo yum` it askes for the user password.  When I give the user password, it tells me that the user `is not in the sudoers file`.  When I type in `sudo yum` again, and type in the root password instead, it gives me a message saying `sorry try again`.

Comment: Right, that "not in the sudoers file" is `sudo` not being set up. Try the `su -` root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65548/discussion-between-codemed-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/613366/install-mysql-on-centos7-with-rpm which advises not using rpm installation for sql server.

Answer (score 28):

Following worked for me.

$yum shell

> remove mariadb-libs
>
> run

exit and then install MYSQL RPM package.

Got idea from following post
https://serverfault.com/questions/613366/install-mysql-on-centos7-with-rpm

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to respond to this old question.  I cannot validate your answer.  However, if someone else wants to validate your answer and post a comment, I would then be happy to mark yours as accepted.

Comment: Got the exact same error message installing MySQL 5.6.51 on RHEL 7. Worked perfectly though I had to run as root to remove mariadb-libs.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly when i want to migrate mariadb to percona. By removing mariadb and install Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-57. I should remove mariadb-libs first like you said

Comment: it works for me, save my day!

Answer (score 13):

Alternative solution which worked for me :

Search for the broken package package : (for e.g. mariadb-libs)

```
$ rpm -qa | grep mariadb-libs
mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
```

Remove this package :

```
rpm -ev --nodeps mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
```

Now simply install, the mysql rpm or mysql-server.
Hope it will solve any dependency of broken package related problem.

Comment: This was the case for me.

Answer (score 10):

Running `yum erase MariaDB*` command worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this while encountering the same error. While I did not have any mariadb libs install it seems the issue was that I had mysql client 8.0 installed. Once removed, I was able to install Mysql server 5.7.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31242038)

Answer (score 0):

Like xs2raid 's answer

If packages for MariaDB are dependencies for other installed packages, you can do like so

```
yum shell
> remove MariaDB-common
> install percona-server-server percona-server-shared-compat
> run
```

That way you can remove MariaDB items while installing percona packages in a signle transaction that won't force you to uninstall packages that depend on MariaDB-common for example

Answer (score 0):

just run to get the package that causes the conflict:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

Now you can remove it

```
yum erase mysql-{your-version}.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.x86_64
```