# Conflict with MySql while installing MariaDB Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, phabricator

I try to install Phabricator on Oracle Linux. I have problem with one of the first step. I try to install MariaDB with the command:

```
yum install mariadb-server mariadb
```

and i receive this:

```
[root@vmphabricator ~]# yum install mariadb-server mariadb
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Package mariadb-server is obsoleted by MariaDB-server, trying to install MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 instead
Package mariadb is obsoleted by MariaDB-client, trying to install MariaDB-client-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.1.16-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-client-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.16-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: galera for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjemalloc.so.1()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-common.x86_64 0:10.1.16-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package galera.x86_64 0:25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0()(64bit) for package: galera-25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package jemalloc.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.627-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlServer) >= 0.2001 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlClient) >= 0.2000 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package boost-program-options.x86_64 0:1.53.0-25.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-PlRPC.noarch 0:0.2020-14.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon) >= 0.13 for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Log) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Test) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Net-Daemon.noarch 0:0.48-5.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                Arch    Version                       Repository   Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 MariaDB-client         x86_64  10.1.16-1.el7.centos          mariadb      39 M
 MariaDB-server         x86_64  10.1.16-1.el7.centos          mariadb     100 M
Installing for dependencies:
 MariaDB-common         x86_64  10.1.16-1.el7.centos          mariadb      43 k
 boost-program-options  x86_64  1.53.0-25.el7                 ol7_latest  154 k
 galera                 x86_64  25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos    mariadb     7.7 M
 jemalloc               x86_64  3.6.0-1.el7                   mariadb     104 k
 perl-DBI               x86_64  1.627-4.el7                   ol7_latest  801 k
 perl-Net-Daemon        noarch  0.48-5.el7                    ol7_latest   50 k
 perl-PlRPC             noarch  0.2020-14.el7                 ol7_latest   35 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  2 Packages (+7 Dependent packages)

Total size: 148 M
Installed size: 635 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of MariaDB-common-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/errmsg-utf8.txt from install of MariaDB-server-10.1.16-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-common-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I am able to do the following steps to install Phabricator instead of this error above but I'm stoped trying running this command:

```
./bin/storage upgrade --user root --password root
```

I receive:

```
MySQL Credentials Not Configured

Unable to connect to MySQL using the configured credentials. You must configure standard credentials before you can upgrade storage. Run these commands to set up credentials:

  phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.host __host__   phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.user __username__   phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.pass __password__

These standard credentials are separate from any administrative credentials provided to this command with __--user__ or
__--password__, and must be configured correctly before you can proceed.

Raw MySQL Error: Attempt to connect to root@localhost failed with error
#2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2).
```

I guess that this problem is caused by the fact that I haven't install MariaDB in a proper way. Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I reinstall mysql-server and the installation worked properly. When I check mysql status I receive:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysqld.service
mysqld.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-08-18 11:59:47 CEST; 35s ago
  Process: 16335 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, s      tatus=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16276 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, sta      tus=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16334 (mysqld_safe)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           ├─16334 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
           └─16487 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql -...
```

But the problem with "MySQL Credentials Not Configured" remains

**SOLVED**

I uninstall all mysql and mariaDB files. I installed mysql again and then I set new passwort and it worked

Comment: you cant have mysql and maridb installed on the same machine, mariadb binaries are the same name as those in mysql. You could use the mysql that is already installed or remove mysql and add mariadb

Comment: @AnthonyStaunton ok so if i don't need mariadb - it is ok. But now how to fix the problem with "MySql Credentials Not Cofigured"??

Comment: make sure the mysql service is runnting "sudo service mysqld status
", then "mysql -uroot -p". change the password with "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'"

Comment: after running `sudo service mysqld status` i receive `mysqld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)` How to fix it?

Comment: Good that you solved! You can create an answer and mark that as solution, instead of writing the solution in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql wont install in CentOS due to conflict with mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113696/mysql-wont-install-in-centos-due-to-conflict-with-mariadb)