# Conflict while Installing MariaDB on Centos6.9 that has Mysql already installed

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, centos6, erpnext

I have VPS Centos 6.9 server with Cpanel, This server has mysql56 installed. I want to replace mysql with MariaDB in order to install [bench erpnext](https://github.com/frappe/bench).
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/install-mariadb-in-centos-6/), and also I removed mysql by:

```
yum remove mysql-server
yum remove mysql-libs
```

but, when I tried to install MariaDB as mentioned in the tutorial:

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client -y
```

this error has been thrown :

```
  Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/mysql from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/msql2mysql from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql_find_rows from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql_waitpid from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlaccess from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqladmin from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlbinlog from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlcheck from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqldump from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlimport from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlshow from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlslap from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/msql2mysql.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlbinlog.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlimport.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlslap.1.gz from install of MariaDB-client-5.5.56-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1.cp1156.x86_64
```

### Error Summary

I saw the similar [Stack Over Flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013905/conflict-with-mysql-while-installing-mariadb-linux), but it has no useful answer for my situation.

**SOLVED**
Removing mysql-client solved this problem.

```
yum remove mysql-client
```

Comment: Use `yum search mysql` to list packages it's worth deleting

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think it is not fair to do such things!
There are tons of similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013905/conflict-with-mysql-while-installing-mariadb-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove MySQL56-client and any other MySQL56 packages as well before installing Maria.

Comment: That is what did i try to do when I typed : 
yum remove mysql-server
yum remove mysql-libs 
Are there are any missed steps?

Comment: yes, **..conflicts with file from package MySQL56-client-5.6.35-1...** indicates it is still installed.  Do a **yum list installed** to see what you missed.