# Unable to install MySQL on CENTOS7

Tags: mysql, centos7

I'm on CentOS 7(CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)) starting from scratch on  a new server trying to install MySQL (7 or 8).

I have followed my steps -which I have successfully completed many times in the past, as well many other sites such as:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/
- https://www.mysql.r2schools.com/how-to-install-mysql-8-on-centos/
- [https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-8-on-centos/#:~:text=MySQL%208%20is%20the%20latest,LInux%20using%20the%20package%20manager](https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-8-on-centos/#:%7E:text=MySQL%208%20is%20the%20latest,LInux%20using%20the%20package%20manager).

and many others

All the methods agree on these steps:

1. Download and add the following MySQL Yum repository

   ```
   sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
   ```

   *Note* I tried different versions 7-5, and 8
2. install the downloaded package

   ```
   sudo yum install mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm -y
   ```
3. install MySQL:

   ```
   sudo yum install mysql-server -y
   ```

On Step #3 is where the installation fails

```
mysql -V
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

And I get all these errors

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libncurses.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtinfo.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
```

I read this post which looks similar, but no luck either

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205500/i-can-not-install-mysql-using-yum-on-centos7

the only version that I'm able to successfully install is a very old mysql version: 5.6

Any ideas/suggestions on what I am missing; or how to solve this?

Comment: Isn't that distro super end of life?

Comment: CentOS was ditched by RedHat recently. Why would you like to work on an OS that is dying as we speak? Support with become non-existent not too far in the future.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. || 

EOF for CentOS7 is 2024 || 
CentO8 was the one that abruptly came to an end this past Dec 2021 ||
CentOS7 is what it was given -

Comment: Is it still receiving non-security updates?

Comment: I would still consider using different distro if it's a new server.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I think I got it. Here is what I did to solve it.

#### Step #1: – Remove previous installed packages and clear cache

```
# look for the mysql installed packages
sudo yum list installed | grep mysql

sudo yum remove mysql80-community-release.noarch

sudo yum clean all --verbose

#manually remove remaining mysql cache folders
#from: https://serverfault.com/questions/1028593/mysql-packages-skipped-dependency-problems
sudo rm -R /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/mysql*

sudo yum update
```

from: https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-8-on-centos/

#### Step #2: – Setup Yum Repository

```
rpm -Uvh https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
```

#### Step #3: – disable all repositories in mysql repo file.

```
sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/' /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo
```

#### Step #4 – Install MySQL Community Server

```
yum --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-community-server
```

Got the following error:

```
The GPG keys listed for the "MySQL 8.0 Community Server" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.


 Failing package is: mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el7.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

From
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/mysql-upgrade-process-failed-the-gpg-keys-listed-for-the-mysql-8-0-community-server-repository-are-already-installed-but-they-are-not-correct-for.697213/

#### Step #5 –import the new GPG key

per comments below, you might need to do '2023' instead of '2022'

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
```

#### Step #6 – Re-run  STEP #3 Install MySQL Community Server

```
yum --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-community-server
```

Got multiple warning message related to every different language; for example the one related to 'english'

```
warning: file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /usr/share/mysql/english: remove failed: No such file or directory
```

However, final messages were successful:

```
Installed:
  mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:8.0.28-1.el7                                                  
  mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:8.0.28-1.el7                                           
  mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:8.0.28-1.el7                                                

Dependency Installed:
  mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:8.0.28-1.el7                                                
  mysql-community-client-plugins.x86_64 0:8.0.28-1.el7                                        
  mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:8.0.28-1.el7                                                
  mysql-community-icu-data-files.x86_64 0:8.0.28-1.el7                                        

Replaced:
  mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.68-1.el7                                                          

Complete!
```

#### Step #7: test

```
mysql -V

# output #
mysql Ver 8.0.28 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

#### Step #8: Double check that no errors when running yum update

```
sudo yum update
```

##### Confirm by starting it manually, checking status,

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
sudo systemctl status mysqld
```

Comment: Great detective work 

Comment: When I run: mysql -V
i got:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: @AhmedSEDDIK, if you look at the path do you have this  that folder/file?  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: @user3891775 Yes, there is the file mysql.sock on the path that you give it to me !! The problem is fixed by restarting the computer. May be i should reboot my laptop so that new configuration take places. Thanks

Comment: the solution was just the (rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022)

Comment: this works for me but after installation, I am not able to login to MySQL. I am trying ```mysql -u root``` also with sudo but it is throwing error

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava - the steps described above are just for package setup:
After you have completed above you have to:
A) get the default given password:
MySQL version 8.0 or higher generates a temporary random password in /var/log/mysqld.log after installation
To see the password run:
sudo grep 'password' /var/log/mysqld.log
Response: A temporary password is generated for root@localhost

B)  Run the secure installation
sudo mysql_secure_installation

Comment: @user3891775: Thank you for the detailed work and comments along the way! I followed this in 2024 and was able to solve the problem with a minor change to Step #5, had to replace 2022 with 2023.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I just imported GPG-KEY:

```bash
sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
```

After that next command runs without errors:

```bash
sudo yum install mysql-server -y
```

Comment: [ec2-user@ip html]$ sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
[ec2-user@ip html]$ sudo yum install mysql-server -y
Last metadata expiration check: 2:58:23 ago on Tue Sep 19 12:15:01 2023.
No match for argument: mysql-server
Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-server

Comment: any idea how to solve this..??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and got stuck on this error

> ***The GPG keys listed for the "MySQL 8.0 Community Server" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.***

even after trying all existing answers.

The following is what worked.

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023
```

and then:

```
yum --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-community-server
```

And everything was successful without warning and errors.

**Start MySQL service**

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
sudo systemctl enable mysqld
```

**Show the default password for the root user**

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Copy the password. This would be used as the root password when you run mysql_secure_installation command.

**Execute the command mysql_secure_installation to secure the MySQL server:**

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Do well to follow the interactive accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -qa | grep mariadb
rpm -e XXX #If there is an already installed mariadb, uninstall it
rpm -e --nodeps xxx //If the preceding delete action does not work, try force delete
```

It did really do the magic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem after step 4, had an error:

```
my.cnf from install of mysql-community-server-8.0.32-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common...
```

I needed to run:

```
yum remove mariadb-libs
```

and then install MYSQL. Found that here >> [MySQL won't install in CentOS due to conflict with mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113696/mysql-wont-install-in-centos-due-to-conflict-with-mariadb)

After that installation of mysql went smooth.