# Unable to access MySQL 8.0.33 on Linux CentOS

Tags: mysql, linux

I have installed MySQL 8 version on my Linux machine and able to check the status but when I'm executing mysql -u root -p, it is giving the below error.

> "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: YES)"

Have tried all the ways discussed in this platform and tried to execute but unable to access MySQL.

Below are the steps I performed until the error.

```
[root@localhost /]# mysql -V

mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

[root@localhost /]# systemctl start mysqld

[root@localhost /]# systemctl status mysqld

● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-06-03 15:03:36 IST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 1107 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1715 (mysqld)
   Status: "Server is operational"
    Tasks: 37
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─1715 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jun 03 15:03:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jun 03 15:03:36 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.

[root@localhost /]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Please help!

Comment: Hi Ergest, same error. Here, in the using password section "No" is displayed.

Comment: [root@localhost /]# mysql -u root 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I followed the link below               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993613/unable-to-install-mysql-on-centos7

Comment: From the link you pasted *MySQL version 8.0 or higher generates a temporary random password in /var/log/mysqld.log after installation To see the password run: sudo grep 'password' /var/log/mysqld.log Response: A temporary password is generated for root@localhost B) Run the secure installation sudo mysql_secure_installation* . Have you verified the logs ?

Comment: Yes, but same error this time as well. I have already tried these options but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest resetting the root password.

Reset MySQL Root Password Using –skip-grant-tables

1.Stop MySQL service

```
 systemctl stop mysqld
```

2.Then start the service with the following option

```
 mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql &
```

3.Then, connect to the MySQL server

```
mysql
```

4.Reload the grants so you will be able to change the password later

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

5.Change password

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_passowrd';
```

6.Reload the grants

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

7.Stop the MySQL server

```
systemctl stop mysqld
```

8.Start MySQL  normally

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

9.Connect with the new password

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Hi Ergest, thank you so much for the help. I'm now able to access the mysql. I uninstalled and re-installed the db and it worked.